# Is it possible to get the following information from BeautifulSoup without a loop or additional module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup4 and Python 3.

I am attempting to scrape a part of a webpage that has the following structure:

```
<h1>Main Title Here<br/>

<small>
Subtitle Here - 
More Pieces of Subtitle Here</small>
</h1>
```

So far, I have tried:

- Printing the text for the entire element `print(soup.find('h1').text)`
  --This prints with excess spaces making it difficult to manuipulate.
- Grabbing the contents for the element
  --This seems to yield the
  same results as text

So, with both methods above my output looks like this:

> Main Title Here *multiple spaces here*
>   *multiple spaces here*          Subtitle Here - 
>   *multiple spaces here*          multiple spaces here         More Pieces of Subtitle Here

These both return the text with line breaks and a lot of spaces.  I have tried the following to clean up the data returned:

- Using Replace() and Strip()
  --This cleans it up a little, however, strip only removes the outermost spaces and replace has the potential of removing all spaces
  (which I do not want)
- Using Decompose() and Extract()
  --This removed everything from
  within the `"small"` tag and returns `<none>` tags.

I would like the output to look like this:
(line 1)  Main Title Here
(line 2)  Subtitle Here - More Pieces of Subtitle Here

Or this would also work:
(1 Line)  Main Title Here, Subtitle Here - More Pieces of Subtitle Here

Basically, I need this condensed to one or two lines with no excess spaces and all html tags stripped.

From what I have read elsewhere on here, I either need to use a for loop to iterate through this small piece of the page (which would also require changing "Find" to "FindAll" to my knowledge, or, I need to import the re module.

Is there anyway to achieve my desired result without using the loop or importing the module?

Here are some other things I have tried (with little or no success):

```
#Grabbing element, then next element separately
    print(soup.findAll('h1')[0].next)
    h=(soup.findAll('small')[0].next)
    h=h.replace('\n', '')
    print(h.strip())

#Grabbing by div and looping through
    i = soup.find('div', attrs={'page-header'})
    children = i.findChildren()
    for child in children:
         print(child)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you rely on the tags within the header rather than on line breaks:

```
h1 = soup.find('h1')
list(h1.strings)[0] # The first string of the header
#'Main Title Here'
h1.find('small').string.strip() # The string in <small>
#'Subtitle Here - \nMore Pieces of Subtitle Here'
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  Tried this out and unfortunately it does not appear to take care of all breaks and spaces, even if I add the "replace" back in.  I'll try a few more variations to see if I can get it working.